# Connecting from Tibco SOTFIRE to SAS datasets on windows

Tags: spotfire

How to create connection from spotfire to SAS datasets?

Comment: Thanks for the question, but try to give as much detail as possible when you ask. Here is a great reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning su919. Your question doesn't provide enough details but the following link will help you out:

http://support.spotfire.com/sr_spotfire65.asp

Select your version at the top to read requirements related to Spotfire. In particular to SAS...

SAS Providers for OLE DB 9.22 or higher

It is possible to import SAS data files (*.sas7bdat, *.sd2, *.sd7) into TIBCO Spotfire directly. The requirement for this functionality is that the SAS Providers for OLE DB 9.22 or higher must first be installed on the client machine.

Click [here](http://support.sas.com/downloads/browse.htm?cat=64) to download SAS Providers for OLE DB (free registration on SAS website required).

NOTE: SAS Providers for OLE DB are not supported for use in Spotfire Web Player (the SAS driver is not thread-safe, which can cause general platform instabilities).

Comment: I've installed the sasoledb_92230 connection but spotfire is stil throwing an import exception error and stacktrace. Any ideas?

Comment: @Garglesoap this question is 3 years old. You need to ask a new question so that people who follow this site can answer. Only I was notified of your comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask